# publishing mvc4 app from vs2012 not picking up release settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I am using VS2012 and having some troubles publishing an mvc4 website.

None of my release settings are applied.

Within my configs I have this

Web.Config

```
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name="***" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
```

Release

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!-- For more information on using Web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->
 <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<appSettings>
    <add key="ApiBaseUrl" value="https://api.mydomain.com/api/"  xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
<!--
In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
"connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
finds an atrribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" 
    connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
      -->
<system.web>
  <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  <authentication mode="Forms" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name="***" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain="www.mydomain.com"/>
  </authentication>
   <!--
  In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
  <customErrors> section of your Web.config file.
  Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
  <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

  <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
    mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
  </customErrors>
-->
</system.web>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <network host="localhost"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
 </system.net>
 <dotless xdt:Transform="Replace" minifyCss="true" cache="true" web="false"  />
 </configuration>
```

I am publishing when set to Release.

Can anyone see anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: One quicky, the transformation for the removal of the debug attribute is <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />

Comment: Are you providing the closing </system.web> in your transformation file?

Comment: @Tommy yes everything is closed. I have included the entire transform config. I made your change however still no joy.

Comment: Do you have location tags in your web.config?

Comment: Thanks Jeff!!!!!that was it. I have location tags set and didnt have them setup. Add this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer :)

Comment: @JeffSiver - that one bit me too not too long ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web.config includes location tags, you need to make sure those are accounted for in the Release config as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Publish Profiles in the Web Publishing Wizard. In VS2010, the web.config transforms were applied according to the build configuration selected at the time of publish, but with the new Web Publishing Wizard I believe it's stored right inside of the Publish Profile. Which I believe is the one they included with VS2012